# Turn off autosave in Xcode 10.1

Tags: xcode10, autosave, xcode10.1, disable

I'm trying to turn off Xcode 10.1 autosave feature, but couldn't find anywhere on the IDE itself.

Also searched extensively online, I've found mentions of autosave but not how to disable it (or even if it's possible).

Would you know? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies not in Xcode, but in the System Settings.
Go to System Settings -> General, and check "Ask to keep changes when closing documents".

Done!

Comment: This does not work for me. Even when checked if I (1) modify a file in Xcode (2) do not choose File -> Save (3) view the file with another program, then the contents will have already been changed. Any other suggestions?